# MinimalBy with argument and value

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

I need to find element of some list `arr` which is minimal by some function `f`.
But I need to get result in form `{elem, f[elem]}`, just like with `FindMinimum`.
Is it possible to do it better than

```
With[{elem = First@MinimalBy[arr, f]},
{elem, f[elem]} ]
```

?

Comment: Try e.g.:  ´ {elem = MinimalBy[arr, f], f[elem]}

Comment: If f is expensive, then you may wish to call it once: With[{expr = {#,f[#]}&/@arr}, MinimalBy[expr,Last]]

Comment: @DanielHuber, Craig Carter, thank you, but without `First` we get `{ {elem}, f[{elem}] }` what is not desired )

Comment: Then try: {elem = MinimalBy[arr, f][[1]], f[elem]}

Comment: @DanielHuber, thanks, in my case it's best solution!